# JavaScript ajax post not work on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Hello Friends :D

I have problem when hiding a `<div>` in Internet Explorer 6,7 and 8 using a jQuery/JavaScript ajax POST.
The following code works fine on other browsers (for example FF,Chrome,Safar and Opera), but it doesn't work in IE.

**below is my script on login page:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#even tr:even").addClass("even");
     $('#login_loader').hide();

        $("#login_form_submit").click(function() {

            $('#login_form_submit').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#login_loader').fadeIn(200);
            $('#login_group').slideUp(500);
            $('#logout_hint').slideUp(500);
            $('#login_contact_form').slideUp(500);

            $.post("action/login.php?act=login", {
                username: $('#login_username').val(),
                password: $('#login_password').val(),
                captcha: $('#login_captcha').val(),

            }, function(response){

                setTimeout("finishAjax('login_group', '"+escape(response)+"')", 1000);

            });

            return false;

        });

    });
```

Can anyone see what the problem is? Thanks ;)

Comment: what happens in ie? an error? nothing? What happens if you do an alert inside of the finishAjax function? Do you see it? If not how about inside the post callback function?

Comment: `captcha: $('#login_captcha').val(),` the last comma could cause the problem...i had some similar issues with IE

Comment: @sofl - Make an answer out of that. I had similar issues with IE being *way* more sensitive about syntax than other browsers.

Comment: @sofl you're on to something. try this in ie: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/PDjn7/ It seems to work for me in in IE8, but not IE7.

Comment: thanks sofl , first problem solved ( `$('#login_loader').hide();` this is now work) but , ajax post still not working , please check at my url : [MyWebsite Login Form](http://panel.irgs.ir)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma in this line:

```
captcha: $('#login_captcha').val(),
```

Comment: first problem solved (`$('#login_loader').hide();` this is now work) but , ajax post still not working , please check at my url : [MyWebsite Login Form](http://panel.irgs.ir/) Thanks